# Angular ng-repeat filter running before data retrieved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a list of appointments that I need to filter by staff member.  I am pulling the appointments from a database using a Breeze controller.  Some appointments have multiple staff members involved, so I need to drill into a child entity of the appointment to find the staff members for each appointment.  I am trying to show a list based on the staff member selected elsewhere using ng-repeat and a filter as follows:

```
<section data-ng-repeat="appt in apptCtrl.appointmentList | filter: apptCtrl.matchStaff(staff)" data-ng-model="apptCtrl.appointmentList" class="apptStaffList">
    <appt-event data-ng-model="appt"></appt-event>
</section>
```

The filter function on my appointment controller is as follows:

```
self.matchStaff = function (query) {
    var staffAppts = [];
    angular.forEach(self.appointmentList, function (a) {
        var staffAppt = a.some(function (s) {
            return s.StaffId === query;
        });
        if (staffAppt) {
            staffAppts.push(a);
        }
    });
    return staffAppts;
};
```

Unfortunately, the self.appointmentList is populated when the controller is initialized, but the list does not return until after the view has already loaded.  Without the filter, the appointments appear as soon as the list is populated.  When matchStaff is called, however, self.appointmentList is just an empty array.

Is there a way to cause the filter to run AFTER the list is populated?  Is there some other way to handle filters?  Is there a way to call the filter with a string in this case?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your question?

Comment: Are you grabbing the data using the http service, Restangular, or anything promise wrapped? You can always execute matchStaff() after the data loads using .then()

Comment: @HuyHoangPham I'm afraid I have not used jsfiddle before.  Also, I needed to remove and consolidate a lot of code because it was extraneous in this case.  I hope this is enough to look at.  [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ChristyPiffat/sdtpLapn/5/)

Comment: @The Brofessor I had thought about executing matchStaff afterwards.  However, I will be showing the appointments for several staff members at a time in separate areas of the grid.  I think I would have to use multiple arrays of appointments (one for each staff member selected).  Some of the appointments involve multiple staff members, so I wanted to make sure that I didn't have one appointment come across as two separate appointments in case it was edited.  I may have to do it this way, but I was hoping the filter could run asynchronously or be triggered to run again when the data was updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the appointmentList in a [resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) method if you are using routes on your application.

```
//config
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
        {
          templateUrl: "app.html",
          controller: "AppCtrl"
          resolve: {
            appointments: function (myAppoimentsService) {
              return myAppoimentsService.fetch();
            }
          }
        }
```

...

```
// controller
app.controller('AppoimentCtrl', ['appointments', function (appointments) {

  this.appoimentList = appointments;
}]);
```

Comment: The appointments are overlaid on top of a grid (left off because it was extraneous).  For each staff member selected, a new column with appointments for that person is overlaid on the grid using a directive to display each appointment.  As a result, the controller with the appointments is initialized when the first person is selected, but would not be re-initialized when the next was selected.  To prevent duplication of appointments, the ones for the next person are concatenated with the original list and then filtered in the column.  Is there a way to do a resolve on part of a controller?

Comment: Resolve is a method for routing. But maybe you need an appointments directive that loads the data when the user is selected and contains the appointment directive. If you could prepare an example it would be easier to help

Comment: I actually do have an appointments directive, but had not included it in my initial jsfiddle.  I have updated it to show this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ChristyPiffat/sdtpLapn/6/).  I have been struggling a bit with the scope.  Is that what I would be using to filter?

Comment: Did you mean a directive for the list itself?